# copy data from one table, format it to another

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to copy a string from one table, format it into date format and place it in another table.I have tried this -

```
$SQL2 = "UPDATE action_data 
SET date_of_call = STR_TO_DATE(date_holding_table.date_1, '%d/%m/%Y') 
FROM date_holding_table WHERE date_holding_table.id = action_data.id";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $SQL2);
```

Which doesnt create any error codes but doesnt copy the data either. I know my source data is ok as I have managed to convert it before using different code.
Thanks

Comment: Execute the SQL code directly, not in your script, and see what happens. If still nothing, execute a simple SELECT, and make sure data is being returned.

Answer (score 1):

> Make sure that in `date_holding_table` table , `date_1` column is of `'%d/%m/%Y'` format else `STR_TO_DATE( date_holding_table.date_1 ,'%d/%m/%Y' )` probably will return NULL and nothing gets updated .

[STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Tested and works :

```
UPDATE
     action_data
    ,date_holding_table
SET
    action_data.date_of_call = STR_TO_DATE( date_holding_table.date_1 ,'%d/%m/%Y' )
WHERE
    date_holding_table.id = action_data.id
```

Test data :

```
-- Table structure for table `date_holding_table`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `date_holding_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;

-- Dumping data for table `date_holding_table`

INSERT INTO `date_holding_table` (`id`, `date_1`) VALUES
(1, '1/5/2013'),
(2, '20/4/2004');

-- Table structure for table `action_data`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `action_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_of_call` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;

-- Dumping data for table `action_data`

INSERT INTO `action_data` (`id`, `date_of_call`) VALUES
(1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(2, '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
```

After running the my `UPDATE` query :

> 2 rows affected.

```
-- Dumping data for table `action_data`

INSERT INTO `action_data` (`id`, `date_of_call`) VALUES
(1, '2013-05-01 00:00:00'),
(2, '2004-04-20 00:00:00');
```

Comment: It does work, thank you. I dont understand why I need to add date_holding_table to the UPDATE though! Many thanks to you all.

Comment: You would need to specify all the tables involved . My syntax is correct but it seems the `STR_TO_DATE` probably is returning `NULL` for some reason which you would need to address first .

Comment: Oh sorry , I miss read that it did not work and updated my answer . However I am glad it worked .

Answer (score 1):

Your [multi-table `UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) syntax for MySQL is incorrect. Table references should go before `SET` clause. Try it this way

```
UPDATE action_data a JOIN date_holding_table d
    ON a.id = d.id
   SET a.date_of_call = STR_TO_DATE(d.date_1, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d0020/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually surprised you are not getting an error.  You didn't specify your database engine, but most of them will support this syntax.

```
update action_data
set date_of_call = STR_TO_DATE(date_holding_table.date_1, '%d/%m/%Y') 
from action_data join date_holding_table on date_holding_table.id = action_data.id
```

Comment: He's clearly using mysql, based on the mysqli_query() call, no?